# Why assigning to const variable does not lead to an error?

Tags: javascript, constants

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rmrG9/

Code:

```
const a = 10
a = 20
alert('a: ' + a)
```

The output is:

```
a: 10
```

Can you explain why the statement `a = 20` did not throw an error?

Comment: Really? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the doc ([**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)):

> None of the major browsers produce any notices or errors if you assign
>   another value to a constant. The return value of such an operation is
>   that of the new value assigned, but the reassignment is unsuccessful
>   only in Firefox and Chrome (at least since version 20).

As `const` is really just a proposal at the moment, browser vendors are free to implement the way they see fit. Note that the standard will most probably define `const` to be [**block-scoped**](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aconst) (and currently it's function-scoped, just as `var` and `function`).